# Eclipse 2021-6 java content assist doesn't provide completions when there is a compile error

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, content-assist

I'm having an issue with content assist not providing completions when there is a compile error on that line.

In the below example I was able to complete the first call to feature() however not the second one.

If I where to write feature() manually it compiles.
[image: Example]

I have Java Proposals turned on and it works fine sometimes but not in situations as shown above.

This wasn't a problem until I upgraded from eclipse 2019 to 2021-6
Is there any option to enable content assist here?

Answer (score 0):

this was fixed by quitting eclipse and deleting `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core\savedIndexNames.txt` and restarting eclipse.