# Issues with auto assist Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded the latest version of Eclipse (2021-06) and I have noticed the next problem that I don't know how to fix.

Before if I was typing `object.get` and pressing [CTRL]+[SPACE], Eclipse was showing me all the methods of my object that start with the word `get`, now it only shows me the assistant if I type `object.` and then I press [CTRL]+[SPACE].

I tried setting under Java -> Editor -> Content Assist -> Auto activation triggers for Java the value `.abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXYZ` but it doesn't fix the issue.

Here are some screenshots of my setup:

[image: Content Assist]
[image: Content Assist - Advanced]

EDIT: It seems to fail depending on the line... weird.
Here if fails:
[image]

Here it doesn't:

[image]

Comment: I cannot reproduce this in Eclipse 2021-06. Please show all your _Java > Editor > Content Assist (> Advanced)_ preferences and example code to reproduce this issue (to show it's not [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265945/6505250)). Which IDE package do you have and did you install additional plugins.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have edited my post with screenshosts. I only installed this plugins: SubClipse 4.3.3 and Eclipse Web Developer Tools 3.22. I'm using Eclipse IDE for Java Developers Version: 2021-06 (4.20.0).

Comment: According to your edit it's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68265945/6505250) (or more general [Eclipse bug 574913](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=574913)). You might consider to update to [Eclipse 2021-09 M1](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2021-09/m1).

Comment: So that did the trick!. however the current M1 has other bugs and it's tricky to use the assitant without messing with your code. I guess we will have to wait to update Eclipse. Thanks for your help.